# Div box doesn't expends when new element inside the box

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the picture bellow, when a error is printed inside the div the div box doesn't extends.

I know is something related to the height of the box but I cant fix it. I tried many things but can't get it solved

What the best way to get this working?

[image]

[image]

stylecssfile.css

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(29, 26, 39);
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 102, 161, 0.15) 0%, rgba(29, 26, 39, 0.15) 35%);
}

.signup-box {
    background-color: #0b0b18;
    padding: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;

}


.user-input {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.user-input p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.signuptext {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px !important;
}

.form-control {
    background-color: rgb(103, 58, 183);
    width: 250px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.registerbut {
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 6px 40px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(103, 58, 183), rgb(81, 45, 168));
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a specific height number for the .signup-box. You need to change the height to the min-height value and it should work.

```
.signup-box {
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: It not working because now the box take all the screen which is not what I want... https://prnt.sc/QvnYsryZdAbp

Comment: It is hard without HTML. I guess I just picked the wrong class. Please just do the same but for form-control class. You need to choose a class just for that box and set it to min-height.

Comment: It doesn't work https://prnt.sc/E6W5AZGYPKIW . I cant put HTML code in my post cause stackoverflow say there to much code.... here a link for the html code https://pastebin.com/dj2EzhJf

Comment: You have multiple styles that are not how they should be. For class .signup-box set min-height: 300px;  height: max-content; But you also need to remove position absolute for your .user-input class. It doesn't need to be absolute, if it is absolute container can't properly measure and this is your problem.